# How do I read the code section of assembly?

Tags: assembly, memory-address

I am writing an assembly program which takes the address of the start of the code section, then loops through each byte of the code section, reading them but not modifying them.

The problem is, when I try to dereference an address, it seems to actually dereference the address in the data section, rather than the code section.

I am using TASM, on Windows.

Is there a way to access the code section, given an address?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a code segment override prefix (`cs:`). I assume you are writing 16 bit code, since windows in 32 bit uses a flat memory space.

Comment: 16 bit code, in 2016!?

Comment: Always include code in your question, even though in this case the answer can be *guessed*